# Formula to Split a Cell Part of a Row and Keep the Rest of the Rows (For a large dataset)

Tags: algorithm, google-sheets

I have a large data set with 500+ rows and three columns:  `names`, `id`, `value`.  I want to split the `names` column into separate rows with one name each, but with copying over the same values for `id` and `value`.

For example, I have this:

```
names               id     value
bob, sam, bill      99     10
harris              95     11
george, john        98     14
tom, harry          97     13
```

And I need to get this:

```
bob         99  10
sam         99  10
bill        99  10
harris      95  11
george      98  14
john        98  14
tom         97  13
harry       97  13
```

I also need to be able to do this in one iteration or two, since I have a total of 500+ rows.  I [setup a test sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GGBhJcr4C5zDAGi71sDNONH0y0L78r-JB9XWu19-DC0/edit?usp=sharing).  Also I need the solution to be in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Spreadsheet API (and I'm loth to sign up to Google), but I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = 2;
var col = 0;
var values = [];
var start = row;

for (;;) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, col, 1, 3);
    var data = range.getValues();

    if (data[0] == "") break;
    var names = data[0].split(/, */);

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        values.push([names[i], data[1], data[2]]);
    }
    row++;
}

var range = sheet.getRange(start, col, values.length, 3);
range.setValues(values);
```

That expands your list in place, overwriting the original. You can make a copy by changing the rows and columns in the last range. (Anything not to do directly with the Spreadsheet API works. Everything else *should* work, but I haven't tested it.)